# How do I print the total or sum of all the digits in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

Im trying to determine whether the number is odd or even, the length of the input and the sum of all the digits in the input.

Heres my attempt:

```
public static int statNum(int input) {
    if(input % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("The number is even");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The number is odd");
    }

    System.out.println(Integer.toString(input).length());

    String number = String.valueOf(input);
    char [] values = number.toCharArray();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + values[i];
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of this number is: " + sum);

    return input;
}
```

If i input 1 the sum is equal to 49, if I input 1234 the input is equal to 202. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can avoid converting to string by extracting digits one at a time: `% 10` will give you the first digit, with `/ 10`, you scale all the digits by 1 position (discarding the old first) and repeat until you have 0.

Comment: @Shampy Hope your issue is resolved, If so pls accept the ans

Answer (score 2):

You are adding char values i.e adding the ASCII value of the char to the sum, You should parse them to int before adding

Do this

```
sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(values[i]));
```

or as @ZouZou suggested, can use

```
sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(values[i]);
```

Comment: The idea is right but that won't compile. Use `Character.getNumericValue(values[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *subtract* the `char` value `'0'`, so you're only adding the *numeric* value above zero, rather than adding the value of the `char` itself (which is its ascii character value):

```
sum = sum + values[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a code to find sum of digits of a number & length of number :

```
int sum=0;
int length=0;
while(input!=0)
{
    sum+=input%10;
    input/=10;
    length++;
}
```